# .append() saving all values in one column. What I am doing wrong here ? I want this to store values at different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

.append() saving all values in one column. What I am doing wrong here? I want this to store values at different columns.    t_dic is a dic contains time domain windows

```
 # conctenate all features names lists and we add two other columns activity ids and user ids will be related to each row
all_columns=time_features_names()+['activity_Id','user_Id']

def Dataset_Generation_PipeLine(t_dic):
    final_Dataset=pd.DataFrame(data=[],columns= all_columns) # build an empty dataframe to append rows

    for i in range(len(t_dic)): # iterate throw each window

        # t_window and f_window should have the same window id included in their keys
        t_key=sorted(t_dic.keys() )[i] # extract the key of t_window
        
        t_window=t_dic[t_key] # extract the t_window

        window_user_id= int(t_key[-8:-6]) # extract the user id from window's key
        window_activity_id=int(t_key[-2:]) # extract the activity id from the windows key

        # generate all time features from t_window 
        time_features = t_axial_features_generation(t_window)
        
        
        # concatenate all features and append the activity id and the user id
        row= time_features + [int(window_activity_id),int(window_user_id)]
         # go to the first free index in the dataframe
        free_index=len(final_Dataset)
        print(row)
        # append the row
        final_Dataset = final_Dataset.append(row)
    return final_Dataset # return the final dataset
```

Comment: Please post the result of: print(row)

Comment: it simply makes many 1D lists and then puts everything in one column.

Comment: `DataFrame.append` warns against doing this iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `extend` instead of `append` in lists, like the code below:

```
a=[[1,2,3]]
b=[[4,5,6]]
a.extend(b)
print(a[1][0]) #for testing
```

or you can use Pandas DataFrame or Numpy Arrays instead of lists.

Comment: He is using the `DataFrame` append.  But if you are going to `append` iteratively, lists are best.

Answer (score 0):

The row needs to be in dictionary format, like this:

```
row= {'name': ['Bob', 'John', 'Jack'], 'when': ['2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00'], 'age': 34,67,45}
```